# How to install packages-dev defined in composer.json

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I am running a Symfony 2.8 based web app. Now I try to follow the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/testing.html) to add PHPUnit support to the project:

```
$ composer require --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge
```

While this adds the `symfony/phpunit-bridge` requirement to the `packages-dev` of my `composer.json` file, not files are actually installed.

Running `update` manually does not change this either:

```
composer update --dev symfony/phpunit-bridge
You are using the deprecated option "dev". Dev packages are installed by default now.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
Nothing to install or update
```

Thus I get an error when trying to run a test

```
./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit -c app src/AppBundle/
-bash: ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit: No such file or directory
```

There is not `bin` subdir in `/vendor`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
$ composer show symfony/phpunit-bridge

name     : symfony/phpunit-bridge
descrip. : Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
keywords : 
versions : * v4.1.0
type     : symfony-bridge
license  : MIT License (MIT) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html#licenseText
source   : [git] https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge.git b3451fc442baaf9169e50491a059ef17582c4424
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/phpunit-bridge/zipball/b3451fc442baaf9169e50491a059ef17582c4424 b3451fc442baaf9169e50491a059ef17582c4424
names    : symfony/phpunit-bridge

autoload
files
psr-4
Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\ => .
exclude-from-classmap

requires
php >=5.3.3

suggests
ext-zip Zip support is required when using bin/simple-phpunit
symfony/debug For tracking deprecated interfaces usages at runtime with DebugClassLoader

conflicts
phpunit/phpunit <4.8.35|<5.4.3,>=5.0
```

Comment: What shows `composer show symfony/phpunit-bridge`?

Comment: I have added the information in an edit

Comment: Did you tried to remove `vendor` directory and run `composer install` again?

Answer (score 1):

After removing the `vendor` dir and re-running `composer install` I noticed the message:

```
Skipped installation of bin bin/simple-phpunit for package symfony/phpunit-bridge: name conflicts with an existing file
```

This problem does not occur anymore after removing the following config from `composer.json`

```
"config" : {
    "bin-dir" : "bin"
},
```

Without these lines the `bin/` folder and the containing files are created correctly.